# What is Google-based account creation linked to? And how does it work?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

```
Confirm Your New Account
You are about to create a new account on 3D Printing Stack Exchange using a login from

 Google
We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites.
```

Does this mean the new Stack Exchange account is somehow bound to the Gmail or in any other way to the currently logged-in Google account?

I can switch Google accounts and create new site-accounts that I haven't got an account yet without problem.

Are they linked to me, the Google account or both?

Why can any Google account simply create a new account if I'm logged into Stack Exchange?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353880/how-does-openid-authentication-work

Comment: So in short the google account I'm currently logged into doesn't matter and won't get any notifications or access to my SE ?

Comment: Worth reading: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, it uses [oauth2](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) - essentially stackexchange tells google "Hey, we have a user who claims to be one of yours - he has this access token" and google goes "Hey, do you want these people to use this token to log you in?"

And from that, SE has its own "network account" and associates all your accounts with that. They use google only for login, and yeah, you can create new accounts with different credencials, google or otherwise.

I'd warn though that if you do get alternate accounts, use them for good, not evil. I have one I use on untrusted systems to chat, when I don't want to use my mod login/google account. If you use it to vote yourself up or other bad things, terrible things will happen.

Comment: I just said, that you can create new network accounts of unvisited sites, without having to enter any kind of login information. Creating alternate accounts is different matter and ofc when you enter and create other emails you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my Stack Exchange profile and the associated Google account, and it has not changed. It also isn't identical with the currently logged-in account. According to Google I'm not logged in and would need to enter my password to do anything (switch accounts), but I can easily make new network accounts associated with my OpenID without having to input login credentials. Interesting.

On the other hand the Gmail account doesn't seem to be able to reset my password in any way, neither the right Gmail account nor the wrong one. Though this may be dependent on the original Stack Exchange registration method, I can't tell.